# How could i use livequery in google chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, livequery

So i am new to this whole thing. I would like to use somehow a jquery plugin, livequery in my extension. How could i achieve this? 
I have tried to load it like this in the manifest.

`"js": [ "scripts/jq.js", "scripts/lq.js", "scripts/some.js" ]`
But this was not working it throwed an error that the `$` has no object `livequery`. 
The question is how can i load the plugin to get it to work? 
EDIT:
some.js contains this part of code:

```
        $("object").livequery(function() {
    var url = $(this).children("embed").attr("src");
    var newurl = url.replace("http", "https");
    $(this).children("param[name=\"movie\"]").val(newurl);
    $(this).children("embed").attr("src",newurl);
    var ht = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(ht);
     });

    $("a.fancy_groups").livequery(function() {
    $("td.kepmeret_txt").css("padding-top","50px");
    $("td.kepmeret_txt").each(function() {
    $(this).children("em").css("padding-left", "95px")
    });
    $(".kepmeret_ico").css("margin-right","4px").css("margin-left","4px").css("width","140px").css("height","80px");//css("width","140px").css("height","80px")
    $("a.fancy_groups").each(function() {
    $(this).children("img.attached_link").attr("src",(this)).css("width","140px").css("height","80px");
            });
```

});

manifest:

```
"js": [ "scripts/jq.js", "scripts/lq.js", "scripts/some.js" ],
```

Where jq.js is:

```
/*! jQuery v1.8.2 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
```

and lq.js is: `/*! Copyright (c) 2010 Brandon Aaron (http://brandonaaron.net)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT_LICENSE.txt)
 * and GPL Version 2 (GPL_LICENSE.txt) licenses.
 *
 * Version: 1.1.1
 * Requires jQuery 1.3+
 * Docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery
 */`
I dont know what is the problem

Comment: It should have worked. If jq.js is jQuery, `lq` is the LiveQuery plugin, then some.js should be able to use jQuery+liveQuery.

Comment: yes but it is not working like expected when i have used that with userscripts then it was fully working and now not

Comment: What is "expected", and how does the current behaviour diverge from that? If you want help, you need to explain the problem and show relevant parts of your code.

Comment: it is not taking changes after document modification, i mean content generated with javascript